# How to create a auto-increment column in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, auto-increment

I want to create auto-increment column in the form 'YYYYMMDD-xxxxx'.

- 'YYYYMMDD' is the date the data was inserted.
- 'xxxxx' is a value that auto increases by 1.

Is this possible? could you tell me how?

Example:

```
20220101-00001,
20220102-00002,
20220102-00003,
...
20220102-99999,

20220701-00001,
20220701-00002,
...
```

Comment: Do you want to actually store it like that, or do you just need this when you run a SELECT?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I want to save it like that.

Comment: Let me guess: no gaps are allowed, right? And what happens if there are more than 99999 entries per day? Do you get duplicates?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe Yes. no gap are allowd. It's used in small production lines, so we don't put in more than 100,000 per day. However, duplicate is not allowed.

Comment: You could use the technique mentioned towards the end of [this article](https://www.cybertec-postgresql.com/en/gaps-in-sequences-postgresql/).

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe Thank you for the answer. but I want is a way to put data consisting of today's date and automatic increment. No gap is required, but it's not important. gap is allowed it if necessary.

Comment: If gaps are allowed then simply use a sequence. If no gaps are allowed - then simply use 2 columns (one for the date and another for the incremental number) and use `INSERT .... SELECT ....,1+COALESCE(0,MAX(counter)) AS counter FROM tbl WHERE dateColumn = xxx`

Comment: @IVOGELOV Thank you for your answer. I think that's the best way.

Comment: @IVOGELOV Oh....I was asked that the number should start from number 1 every month. Unfortunately, I don't think I can use this method.

Comment: Why not? You can reset the sequence every 1st of the month at 00:00:01 by some cron.